# How to lock the keyboard in Mac OS X, but not the screen?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I want to prevent users from typing anything on the keyboard, but still show the screen (so usual locking will not help). Unplugging the keyboard is not the answer I'm looking for, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[**KeyboardCleanTool**](https://folivora.ai/keyboardcleantool) is a tool which 'locks' the keyboard. It can be enabled or disabled with the mouse.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try [MollyGuard](http://mollyguard.infinitemonkeytheory.com):

> MollyGuard is a small menu bar application that enables you to lock and unlock your keyboard and, optionally, mouse or trackpad with a hotkey combination. When locked, no input is accepted from the keyboard or mouse (other than the hotkey combination, otherwise you wouldn't be able to unlock your input devices).

Comment: Sadly no longer available.  Hasn't been updated in ages, and now even their web site is gone

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you [KeyboardLocker](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keyboardlocker/id1444996429) for Mac. It fits perfectly to me.

Comment: No longer available