# Can you recommend xtrlock alternative for Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mac

So, I have checked several questions here ([one of them](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219501/how-to-lock-the-keyboard-in-mac-os-x-but-not-the-screen)  please note, from 8 years ago), as well as at Apple Support Community ([here's one of them and it's not very useful](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251593239?sortBy=best)). I have tried KeyboardCleanTool, that's a nice solution for cleaning, but that's not what I am looking for. Not at all. I found MollyGuard at one of those aggregator web-sites and it doesn't work in any case. So, what I want actually is xtrlock: keyboard locked, mouse locked, display working, unlocked via hotkey. Is there any tool/option/anything?